# Get keywords from bookmarks from firefox

Tags: mac, firefox

I use a load of keywords for my bookmarks in firefox.  Is it possible to print this all from the command line (I am using a mac).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way I know is you can download the addon called '**pentadctyl**' addon which helps you to list all the keywords by typing the command `:bmarks -keyword`